# Twitter API throws error : 'API' object has no attribute 'search'

Tags: python, object, twitter, tweepy

The following code I wrote was intended to retweet tweets with  #programming. But, anything I run the code I get an error "search" object is not an attribute of the Twitter API. The error is posted below the code. Thanks

```
import tweepy
import time 

# get api code and password(secret)
comsumers_key = '#########'
comsumers_secret = '######'

token_key = '#########'
token_secret = '###########'


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(comsumers_key,comsumers_secret)
auth.set_access_token(token_key, token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

hashtag = "programming"
tweetNum = 20
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, hashtag).items(tweetNum)


def bot1():
    for tweet in tweets:
        try:
            tweet.retweet()
            print("retweet")
            time.sleep(50)
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print(e.reason)
            time.strftime(20)
bot1()
```

**error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sonter/tweetbot/bot1.py", line 48, in <module>
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, hashtag).items(tweetNum)
AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'search'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Cursor`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/pagination.html?highlight=Cursor#tweepy.Cursor) expects a regular `api` method, but looking at its [reference doc](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=search) there is no `search` only, but :

- `search_30_day`
- `search_full_archive`
- `search_tweets`
- `search_users`
- `search_geo`

Maybe you meant one of them ?